# ObjC/Cocoa: Get fill color property of current graphics context

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've run around in circles through the Cocoa docs, and I just can't find the answer to this question.

I can retrieve the current graphics context by sending a 'currentContext' message to the NSGraphicsContext class. I can also set the fill color of the current context by sending a 'set' message to an NSColor object.

However, after sending set, how would I retrieve that value from the current context. What is the equivalent 'get' message for the 'set' that sets the fill color?

I thought it would be an instance method on an NSGraphicsContext object, but I couldn't find the method (or pretty much any getters for that object).

Much appreciated for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't get detailed information about the current graphics context state. Instead before you make any changes you save the graphics context state to a per-thread stack with `saveGraphicsState`. Then when you are done you retrieve the previous state with `restoreGraphicsState`.

Comment: But I need the detailed information about the current graphics context state.

Comment: @claytontstanley: For what purpose?

Comment: drawAtPoint:withAttributes: ; Draw string with current graphics context fill color.

Comment: @claytontstanley: You can do that by using Core Text and [its `kCTForegroundColorFromContextAttributeName` attribute](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_StringAttributes_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCTForegroundColorFromContextAttributeName). (You could try using the attribute with Cocoa text drawing, but that's not guaranteed to work.)

Comment: So, there is no way to "extract" a `CGColorRef` or `NSColor` from this "context"?  Seems as if there IS... but "someone" wants us to just "shut-up and use `CoreText`", eh?

Comment: @alexgray I couldn't figure out how, and I couldn't get the Core Text method to work either. I worked around this issue by keeping track of context changes in a global variable that I controlled.